# Android Fragment for tablets and phone

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I want to do something like that. An picture is easier than words:
[image]

And when the user clicks on a button on the Fragment B, the fragment B changed but not the A.
I've made two different layout (A portrait and a land one). The first one has a layout like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.my.app.ContactsFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/contacts_fragment" />
```

I've a button in my fragment layout with a simple activity call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And the land one is like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.my.app.ContactsFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/contacts_fragment" />

<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.my.app.HomeFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I change the inner fragment using the following code:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
NextFragment nextFrag = new NextFragment();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nextFrag);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

This part works well.

I have two questions now:

- How to put these two ways to change the content in the main activity? I mean, in the main activity, a fragment should call the second way, but in a normal activity, I need to call the first.
- If I click on an item in the fragment A, and then I click on the button in fragment B that changes the fragment to NextFragment. If I click on another item and i do the same. I can go back to the first user. Is there a way to dump the stack when clicking on a new item ?

Thanks for your help.

Ps: I'm using the native fragment lib not the support v4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm struggling to understand the specifics of your 2 questions, as they are vague and do not give enough detail.

However, since you want your `Fragment`s to be changed out at runtime, you **should not** put `<fragment/>` in your layout files. Your current architecture makes it impossible to change out the `Fragment`s in your layouts, which is not what you want.

> Note: When you add a fragment to an activity layout by defining the fragment in the layout XML file, you cannot remove the fragment at runtime. If you plan to swap your fragments in and out during user interaction, you must add the fragment to the activity when the activity first starts.

You should be using `FrameLayout` containers for your `Fragment`s in your layout files, and have a **single** `Activity` add `Fragment`s to those `FrameLayout` containers depending on if they are there. This will allow the app to create 1 `Fragment` in portrait and 2 `Fragment`s in landscape (given you have have a layout for each orientation). This will also allow you to be able to swap out `Fragment`s as your please, and add them to the back stack.

And example of this **Google recommended** approach can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html).

Comment: Thanks, I will replace the layout with some FrameLayout.

Comment: A better way to ask my question: How to determine if the fragment is called in "dual mode" or simple one ?

Comment: Depending on the `FrameLayout` containers it gets in the layout it is provided. If it has `fragment_container_a`, it adds `FragmentA` to it, if it gets `fragment_container_b`, it adds `FragmentB` to it. Like in the Google example, `if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container_a) != null)`. Then, you just create a portrait layout with a `fragment_container_a` and put that in the `layout` folder, and a landscape layout with `fragment_container_a` and `fragment_container_b` and put that in the `layout-land` folder. Now depending on the layout the `Activity` gets, it adds the right `Fragment`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a good solution from [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/04/handle-different-layout-for-phone-and.html).